# Can I pass custom command line arguments in loadimpact/k6 scripts?

Tags: performance-testing, load-testing, k6

As indicated in the official loadimpact/k6 documentation, we are able to execute k6 scripts as follows:

```
k6 run github.com/loadimpact/k6/samples/http_get.js
```

Is it possible to pass in custom command line arguments into a k6 test?  For instance, let's say that I would like to pass in a URL and then reference this URL from within the script.

Is this supported out of the box? If so, how can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 7):

This use case is actually covered very well in the documentation, I just happened to miss it.

https://docs.k6.io/docs/environment-variables

Answer (score 3):

For single argument:
`k6 run -e ENVIRONMENT=test2 scripts/test2GetWorkOrder.js`
and For multiple arguments:
`k6 run -e ENVIRONMENT=test2 -e WOID=107376 scripts/test2GetWorkOrder.js`

you need to put a "-e" before every argument you pass through the script.